# Scale while keep horizontal align

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have WPF control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.LabelWithUnit"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="150">
       <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Grid Width="150">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="ValueLabel" Grid.Column="0" Content="1013.0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                <Label x:Name="UnitLabel" Grid.Column="1" Content="m/s" Margin="1" FontSize="10" />
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

**How it behave now:**

Default:

[image]

When width increased: 
*(this is what i need to change)*
[image]

That how it scales when i increase height:*(that should stay as it is)*
[image]

**How it should behave:**

[image]

*(only this behavior should change - "m/s" should stick to top-right corner):*
[image]

[image]

So, "m/s" part should always stick to top-right corner and numeric part should stay somehow near middle. When i increase `Height` of my control, it should scale both `Label`s.

**EDIT: more pictures added.**

Answer (score 0):

Change the stretching on the `ViewBox` control:

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="UpOnly" Stretch="Uniform">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Width from your grid will solve your problem.

```
<Grid Width="150">
```

Edit

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="ValueLabel" Grid.Column="0" Content="1013.0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
        <Label x:Name="UnitLabel" Grid.Column="1" Content="m/s" FontSize="10" />
    </Grid>
```

EDIT

As try this below,

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" MaxHeight="150" MinHeight="10" MaxWidth="800" MinWidth="10"  Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label x:Name="ValueLabel" Content="1013.0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
   </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" MaxHeight="150" MinHeight="10" MaxWidth="800" MinWidth="10"  Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label x:Name="UnitLabel" Content="m/s" FontSize="10" />
   </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Without Width "m/s" will stick to numeric part instead of what i need.

Comment: @nuclearsweet you can remove ViewBox is there any specific reason for using ViewBox ?

Comment: without ViewBox labels will not scale when i change height of my control, so i need it.

Comment: @nuclearsweet i have added an edit check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
<Label x:Name="UnitLabel" Grid.Column="1" Content="m/s" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

EDIT: I am also unsure how these columns are helping you

Comment: HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" make almost same effect as columns. So if i remove columns i still get same result when increase width of my control when it placed on window.

Comment: @nuclearsweet I think I am not understanding the problem. Is the issue that the text isnt stretching, or is it that it is positioned incorrectly?

Comment: Its position is incorrect. I want to scale text size when i change height of control and keep it size and relative positions when i change width of control. So if i increase width of control label "m/s" should stick to top-right control corner, instead of current place (you can see it at my pictures).

Answer (score 0):

I get the style you wish simply swapping VerticalAlignment of Labels to Stretch

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.LabelWithUnit"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="150">
       <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Grid Width="1900">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="ValueLabel" Grid.Column="0" Content="1013.0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
                <Label x:Name="UnitLabel" Grid.Column="1" Content="m/s" Margin="1" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox Margin="0">
            <Label Margin="0" Padding="1" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="3,0">
                <Label Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```